# 404 error with Slim - tried everything

Tags: php, android, mod-rewrite, xampp, slim

I'm trying to build an API for the first time by using PHP to access a MySQL server, and going off of AndroidHive's tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/) but customizing it to be my own simple API instead of the task manager one listed. My problem is, I can't even get to the part where I test anything (I'm using XAMPP for Mac) because I keep getting 404 errors when I attempt to access a method in my index.php file.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

I already changed my XAMPP Apache httpd.conf file to "AllowOverride All" as per the [Slim documentation instructions](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-URL-Rewriting), and tried restarting the server a billion times but to no avail. No matter what I do, if I ever try to test any of the URLs in my index file (for instance at localhost/w_manager/v1/register) it just returns a 404 not found error.

I even updated my .htaccess file to add in "RewriteBase /v1" though that did not seem to make much of a difference - got another 404 object not found error.

I've also looked around on Stackoverflow a ton. I'm about to pull out my hair. Does anyone have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you access the index.php file?

Comment: @MikaTuupola No I can't - at least not via browser. Nor can I access the v1 folder (get 404s for both) I can, however, access the root folder that contains v1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I seem to have fixed it - not exactly sure how, unfortunately, but what I did was go back and copy the sample code into my own and make alterations (after I noticed that the sample code worked.) One major change I made was that in my index.php file, I moved the Slim request definitions at the beginning and moved all other functions to the end, just before $app->run(). Hope this will help someone else!

Comment: To be clear: my request seems to be working, although I still cannot view the v1 folder in my browser without a 404 error.